# Trigger event in dojo using event handler or programmaticaly

Tags: jquery, dojo

In jquery, we can use following script to manually trigger event. Assume there is some event object - orignalEvent

```
var h = jQuery._data(SOME_NODE, "handle");
h(originalEvent);
```

In dojo, Can we trigger event on some node in similar fashion ?

Answer (score 1):

You use dojo.emit

```
require(["dojo/on"], function(on){
  on.emit(EventTarget, "someEvent", {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: true
  });
});
```